# How to include many tabs inside a big tab (not page)

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have 4 tabs inside a page and what I want is that those 4 tabs are grouped inside one big tab. All inside the same page.

I used Row {.tabset .tabset-fade} to create the 4 tabs. I still don´t know how to create the big tab

[image]